# disable a jquery plugin in xs view in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, view

I used box loader plugin in my bootstrap project. I want to disable this plugin ONLY in xs view. please help me how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can respond to CSS3 media query state changes within JavaScript. The key API is `window.matchMedia`. This is passed a media query string identical to those used in CSS

```
// media query event handler
if (matchMedia) {
    var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {
    if (mq.matches) {
        // window width is at max 768px
        // Disable plugin
    }
    else {
        // window width is larger than 768px
        // Enable plugin
    }
}
```